# How to bring last user purchase in shopify?

Tags: javascript, shopify, e-commerce, cart

I need to bring the last product or products that a user has bought in shopify and show it in the cart. in shopify object or document there is nothing of it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include your code, approaches and errors you face. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as nobody will code all of this for you nor is StackOverflow a "Implement this for me" platform.

Comment: If a customer is logged in, you have access to the customer object. The customer object has a record of previous orders. See: https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/customer#customer-orders